# Parquet issue with infering schema on int column containing Null

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I am reading the s3 key and converting it into parquet using pandas. And before converting into parquet I am type casting it so that pyarrow can infer the schema correctly.

The snippet looks something like below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)['Body'].read()), sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)

df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype('int')

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
pq.write_table(table, buf, compression='snappy')
```

So far so good.

The problem is, when int column has null value, pandas will take it as an object offcourse. Is there any way to typecast it into 'int'. One way could be to do fillna(0) or with 99999 first and then do the typecasting. It worked but then Null and 0 or 99999 has different meaning in that column.

So any idea how to typecast it into int? or anything I can do to modify the code above to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

From the pandas documentation:

> Because NaN is a float, a column of integers with even one missing values is cast to floating-point dtype

Since version 0.24 there are extended integer types which are capable of holding missing values. Typecast to `dtype="Int64"`

You can find more information under 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

EDIT: The proposed workaround in Arrow is

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa


def from_pandas(df):
    """Cast Int64 to object before 'serializing'"""
    for col in df:
        if isinstance(df[col].dtype, pd.Int64Dtype):
            df[col] = df[col].astype('object')
    return pa.Table.from_pandas(df)


def to_pandas(tbl):
    """After 'deserializing', recover the correct int type"""
    df = tbl.to_pandas(integer_object_nulls=True)

    for col in df:
        if (pa.types.is_integer(tbl.schema.field_by_name(col).type) and
            pd.api.types.is_object_dtype(df[col].dtype)):
                df[col] = df[col].astype('Int64')

    return df


df = pd.Series([0, 1, None, 2, 822215679726100500], dtype='Int64', name='x').to_frame()
# df = pd.Series([0, 1, 3, 2, 822215679726100500], dtype='Int64', name='x').to_frame()
# df = pd.Series([0, 1, 3, 2, 15], dtype='Int64', name='x').to_frame()
# df = pd.Series([0, 1, 3, 2, 15], dtype='int16', name='x').to_frame()

df2 = to_pandas(from_pandas(df))    
df2.dtypes
```

All credits to Thomas Buhrmann

Comment: Let me try it because I am not sure whether pyarrow will parse this as integer or something else. And I want it to have same data type as that in the external table. Offcourse.

Comment: You will probably get an error from arrow: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5379 :(